# Using FFmpeg -lavfi to calculate the SSIM of each frame

Tags: ffmpeg

I would like to be able to take a single video, run it through ffmpeg, and have it spit out a log containing the SSIM of each frame with respect to the previous - that is, I want the SSIM scores comparing the previous frame to the current one.

I am attempting to do so by running ffmpeg with the same video input twice, with the second input skipping ahead by one frame.

```
ffmpeg -i .\a.mp4 -i .\a.mp4 -filter_complex "[1:v]select=gte(n\,1)[f]" -map 0:v:0 -map "[f]" -lavfi ssim -f null -
```

When attempting to run this, I am given the error:

```
Cannot find a matching stream for unlabeled input pad 1 on filter Parsed_ssim_0
```

Is there a way I can correct this so that the second input skips one frame and both are run through `-lavfi ssim`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to perform all filtering in a single filtergraph.

`ffmpeg -i .\a.mp4 -i .\a.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=N/FR/TB[v0];[1:v]select=gte(n\,1),setpts=N/FR/TB[v1];[v0][v1]ssim=f=stats.log" -f null -`

Comment: ffmpeg says  `Filter setpts has an unconnected output` is this normal?

Comment: No see edited answer